# Back-projecting Pixel to 3D Rays in World Coordinates using PseudoInverse Method

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, projective-geometry, computational-geometry, image-processing

For perspective projection with given camera matrices and rotation and translation we can compute the 2D pixel coordinate of a 3D point.

[image]

using the projection matrix,

$$
P = K [R | t]
$$

where $K$ is intrinsic camera matrix, $R$ is rotation $t$ is translation. The projection is simple matrix multiplication $x = P X $. 
Zisserman's [book](http://cvrs.whu.edu.cn/downloads/ebooks/Multiple%20View%20Geometry%20in%20Computer%20Vision%20(Second%20Edition).pdf), pg. 161 suggests using $3 \times 4$ projection matrix and taking pseudoinverse. Then one would compute $X$ which defined up to scale which can then be interpreted as the ray starting from camera center going to infinity. I quickly coded this up, I took $Z$ as depth, so I translated the camera in $Y$ direction (up 1 meter), and after retrieving $X$ flipped $Y,Z$ for plotting (most projective geom. math seems to be built to make $Z$ depth),

```
K = [[ 282.363047,      0.,          166.21515189],
     [   0.,          280.10715905,  108.05494375],
     [   0.,            0.,            1.        ]]
K = np.array(K)
R = np.eye(3)
t = np.array([[0],[1],[0]])
P = K.dot(np.hstack((R,t)))

import scipy.linalg as lin

x = np.array([300,300,1])
X = np.dot(lin.pinv(P),x)
X = X / X[3] 
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
w = 20
f = plt.figure()
XX  = X[:]; XX[1] = X[2]; XX[2] = X[1]
ax = f.gca(projection='3d')
ax.quiver(0, 0, 1., XX[:3][0], XX[:3][1], XX[:3][2],color='red')
ax.set_xlim(0,10);ax.set_ylim(0,10);ax.set_zlim(0,10)
ax.quiver(0., 0., 1., 0, 5., 0.,color='blue')
ax.set_xlabel("X")
ax.set_ylabel("Y")
ax.set_zlabel("Z")
ax.set_title(str(x[0])+","+str(x[1]))
ax.set_xlim(-w,w);ax.set_ylim(-w,w);ax.set_zlim(-w,w)

ax.view_init(elev=29, azim=-30)
fout = 'test_%s_01.png' % (str(x[0])+str(x[1]))
plt.savefig(fout)
ax.view_init(elev=29, azim=-60)
fout = 'test_%s_02.png' % (str(x[0])+str(x[1]))
plt.savefig(fout)
```

These images below are the result (blue arrow shows the normal vector perpendicular to the image plane, the images demonstrate all x=10,300 y=10,300 combinations):

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I give the camera/ray plot for each pixel from two different angles.

Do these results look sensible? 10,10 and 200,200 looked odd, I played around with signs a little bit, if I translate up using negative -1, and using -Z after X calc., things improve somewhat?

```
t = np.array([[0],[-1],[0]])
..
XX  = X[:]; XX[1] = X[2]; XX[2] = -X[1]
```

I do not know why that is.

Comment: A pixel would not be a ray but rather a cone or pyramid. But the "center" of that cone/pyramid in some sense will of course be a ray.

Comment: A pyramid.. sorry, how is that possible? Because a pixel is kind of rectangular-ish, and that expands into a pyramid?

Comment: A pixel is how the camera sampled the pixel which depends on the electronics of the CCD elements and stuff like that. Unless we know that, then we can't really say exactly which shape it had. But yes you can approximate it with the center ray for the pixel.

Comment: Although I think it would be difficult for most people on here to tell if the results are right. What are the red and blue arrows? Bear in mind that many on this site may not know a lot of python.

Comment: Okay - so the blue arrow is the normal to the camera's image plane. The red arrow is the beginning piece of the ray starting from the camera center, goes through the pixel, pointing towards the outside world, a piece of the backprojected ray I am looking for.

Comment: As a start, take known points in the *world* coordinate system. Project them to the image (I assume that you can do that successfully), then feed those points back through your inversion code to see if you get the right result.

Comment: Also, I don’t recommend using this method when a more numerically-stable one (described in the same place in the book) is available. The condition number of $PP^T$ for your example is very large, so multiplying by its inverse can lead to numerical instability. On the other hand, the condition number of $M$ isn’t horribly large, and is several orders of magnitude smaller than that of $PP^T$, at any rate.

Comment: Can’t you just rotate the plot instead of flipping the $y$- and $z$- axes? That’s an orientation-changing transformation, so will introduce sign changes that are just going to muddy the waters for you.

Comment: @amd about numerical stability: most numerical packages would use SVD to implement the pseudoinverse, instead of calculating the dot product with the transpose, so I think I'm safe there...

Comment: You might’ve mentioned the overall problem that you’re trying to solve (that you describe in your deleted answer) in the first place. If you’re trying to map from the image to a known world-coordinate plane, there are very straightforward ways to construct that transformation directly that you can find by searching here. One recent one is https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2215736/265466, which might not directly apply to your situation, but describes a simple way to build that map.

Comment: Finally, instead of flipping axes around, why aren’t you rotating the camera so that it points in the direction that you’d like? That’s what the $R$ matrix is for, after all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of trying to debug your code and verify all of those back-mappings, I’m going to describe a way for you to check your own results objectively. If you don’t have a good idea of what the results should be, then I don’t really see how you can tell whether or not they’re “reasonable.”

Assuming that there’s no skew in the camera, the matrix $K$ has the form $$K=\begin{bmatrix}s_x&0&c_x\\0&s_y&c_y\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$ The values along the diagonal are $x$- and $y$- scale factors, and $(c_x,c_y)$ are the image coordinates of the camera’s axis, which is assumed to be normal to the image plane ($z=1$ by convention). So, in this coordinate system, the direction vector for a point $(x,y)$ in the image is $(x-c_x,y-c_y,1)$ and to get the corresponding direction vector in the (external) camera coordinate system, divide by the respective scale factors: $((x-c_x)/s_x,(y-c_y)/s_y,1)$. This is exactly what you get by applying $K^{-1}$, which is easily found to be $$K^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}1/s_x&0&-c_x/s_x\\0&1/s_y&-c_y/s_y\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$ using your favorite method. Finally, to transform this vector into world coordinates, apply $R^{-1}$, which is just $R$’s transpose since it’s a rotation. The resulting ray, of course, originates from the camera’s position in world coordinates. It should be a simple matter to code up this cascade explicitly, after which you can compare it to the results that you get by any other method that you’re experimenting with.

In this specific case, $R$ is just the identity matrix, so there’s nothing else to do once you’ve got the direction vector in camera coordinates. We have $$s_x=282.363047 \\ s_y=280.10715905 \\ c_x=166.21515189 \\ c_y=108.05494375$$ so the internal-to-external transformation is approximately $$\begin{align}x&\to x/282.363-0.589 \\ y&\to y/280.107-0.386.\end{align}$$ Applying this to the point $(20,20)$ from your previous question gives $(-0.518,-0.314,1)$, which agrees with the direction vector computed there. Taking $(10,10)$ instead results in $(-0.553,-0.350,1)$, which you can then check against whatever your code produced, and so on.

All that aside, there’s a gotcha when using the pseudoinverse method described by Zisserman. He gives the following equation for the back-mapped ray: $$\mathbf X(\lambda)=P^+\mathbf x+\lambda\mathbf C.$$ Note that the parameter is a coefficient of $\mathbf C$, the camera’s position in world coordinates, not of the result of back-mapping the image point $\mathbf x$. Converted into Cartesian coordinates, there’s a factor of $\lambda+k$ (for some constant $k$) in the denominator, so this isn’t a simple linear parameterization. To extract a direction vector from this, you’ll need to convert $P^+\mathbf x$ into Cartesian coordinates and then subtract $\mathbf C$.

To illustrate, applying $P^+$ to $(10,10,1)$ produces $(-0.553,-0.175,1.0,-0.175)$, so the ray is $(-0.553,-t-0.175,1.0,t-0.175)$. In Cartesian coordinates, the back-mapped point is $(3.161,1.0,-5.713)$ and subtracting the camera’s position gives $(3.161,2.0,-5.713)$. To compare this to the known result above, divide by the third coordinate: $(-0.553,-0.350,1.0)$, which agrees.

*Update 2018.07.31:* For finite cameras, which is what you’re dealing with, Zisserman suggests a more convenient back-projection in the very next paragraph in equation (6.14). The underlying idea is that you decompose the camera matrix as $P = \left[M\mid\mathbf p_4\right]$ so that the back-projection of an image point $\mathbf x$ intersects the plane at infinity at $\mathbf D = ((M^{-1}\mathbf x)^T,0)^T$. This gives you the direction vector of the back-projected ray in world coordinates, and, of course, the camera center is at $\tilde{\mathbf C}=-M^{-1}\mathbf p_4$, i.e., the back-projected ray is $$\tilde{\mathbf X}(\mu) = -M^{-1}\mathbf p_4+\mu M^{-1}\mathbf x = M^{-1}(\mu\mathbf x-\mathbf p_4).$$ This parameterization of the ray doesn’t suffer from the non-linearity mentioned above.

Comment: Quick note: I plotted $(3.161,2.0,−5.713)$ and it is pointing to the lower right corner of the image plane, looking through the camera center towards +Z. I believe I'll have to play the signs a little to get the direction to its final form (literature says pinhole model negates $Y,Z$ and swaps them).

Comment: @BB_ML Well, if you want to end up with cargo-cult code by “playing with the signs,” that’s your business. Sign reversals caused by the projection should be obvious after staring at the diagram that you included in your questions for a bit. There’s always going to be one somewhere because the standard coordinate system is right-handed looking toward the origin, but we’re looking away from it when viewing the projected image. That’s easily dealt with by either aiming the camera down the negative $z$-axis (which makes more sense to me) or adding a reflection to the transform chain.

Comment: Can you explain why we just have to multiple only by the inverse of R to convert from camera coordinates to world coordinates? Why omit the translation vector?

Answer (score 2):

Pseudoinverse method works, below is the example for pixel 215,180 (upperleft corner of image is (0,0)), the ray for this pixel goes towards lower right from the POV of a person looking from behind camera center towards the Y axis. Due to pinhole camera model / perspective projection, some changes on axis' was necessary (I could switch while plotting but the code below is part of another analysis I had to perform in familiar 3D space).

```
from PIL import Image

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import scipy.linalg as lin

K = [[ 282.363047,      0.,          166.21515189],
     [   0.,          280.10715905,  108.05494375],
     [   0.,            0.,            1.        ]]
K = np.array(K)
R = np.eye(3)
t = np.array([[0],[1.],[0]])
P = K.dot(np.hstack((R,t)))
C = np.array([0., 0., 1.])
p1 = np.array([215, 180, 1.])

X = np.dot(lin.pinv(P),p1)
X = X / X[3]
XX  = np.copy(X)
XX[1] = X[2]; XX[2] = X[1]; XX[2] = -XX[2]
w = 10
f = plt.figure()
ax = f.gca(projection='3d')
xvec = C - XX[:3] 
xvec = -xvec
ax.quiver(C[0], C[1], C[2], xvec[0], xvec[1], xvec[2],color='red')
ax.set_xlim(0,10);ax.set_ylim(0,10);ax.set_zlim(0,10)
ax.quiver(0., 0., 1., 0, 5., 0.,color='blue')
ax.set_xlabel("X")
ax.set_ylabel("Y")
ax.set_zlabel("Z")
ax.set_xlim(-w,w);ax.set_ylim(-w,w);ax.set_zlim(-w,w)
ax.view_init(elev=5, azim=100)
plt.savefig('out1.png')
ax.view_init(elev=5, azim=50)
plt.savefig('out2.png')
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since this is the first and only Google result that actually helps, and it took quite a while to create, here it is in Numpy

````
import numpy as np


def convert_nx2_to_homo_3xn(points_nx2: np.array):
    return np.hstack([points_nx2, np.ones((points_nx2.shape[0], 1))]).T


def convert_nx3_to_homo_4xn(points_nx3: np.array):
    return np.hstack([points_nx3, np.ones((points_nx3.shape[0], 1))]).T


def cast_2d_points_as_3d_rays(sub_pixels_nx2: np.array, proj_3x4: np.array):
    """
    see Harley & Zisserman pg 162, section 6.2.2, figure 6.14
    see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/597489/541203

    cast rays from camera center through the sub_pixels_nx2. Return camera center and ray directions.
    """
    m_3x3 = proj_3x4[:, :3]
    p4_3x1 = proj_3x4[:, 3]
    m_inv_3x3 = np.linalg.inv(m_3x3)

    # projection matrix to camera center
    camera_center_3x1 = np.expand_dims(-m_inv_3x3 @ p4_3x1, 1)
    camera_center_homo_4x1 = np.vstack([camera_center_3x1, 1])

    # projection matrix + pixel locations to ray directions
    sub_pixels_homo_3xn = convert_nx2_to_homo_3xn(sub_pixels_nx2)
    ray_directions_3xn = m_inv_3x3 @ sub_pixels_homo_3xn
    ray_directions_homo_4xn = convert_nx3_to_homo_4xn(ray_directions_3xn.T)
    ray_directions_homo_4xn[3, :] = 0  # this is a direction

    return ray_directions_homo_4xn, camera_center_homo_4x1

```
````