# Back-projecting Pixel to 3D Rays with an origin different than zero

Tags: projection-matrices

I am trying to reproject a pixel in a calibrated camera image into a 3D ray. I have found this answer which helped me a lot, and have almost everything running

[Back-projecting Pixel to 3D Rays in World Coordinates using PseudoInverse Method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2237994/back-projecting-pixel-to-3d-rays-in-world-coordinates-using-pseudoinverse-method?newreg=2dc63084a6d04f9d88bbb60dd8a78e35)

However, for my application it is important to be able to change the starting point of the ray.

**In the example above, the starting coordinate t was (0,1,0). I thought I could just change this vector, but changing it also changes the direction of my vector. I would think this is wrong, since the direction of the ray should be the same, regardldess of the starting point. Right?**

I have tried multiplying R*t to account for the rotation before applying the translation, but that doesn't seem to work either.

How can I change starting point from (0,1,0) to the correct starting point of my camera

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean by “change the starting point of the ray.” A point in the image is by definition the image of a ray that starts at the camera’s position, which happens to be somewhere other than world-coordinate origin in the example in the linked question. The same algorithm applies regardless of the camera’s position, however.

Comment: Thank you amd for your answer. My logic came from the fact that in the projection formula you can set a starting point different than [0,0,0], so I figured I should use that to change the origin of the ray. For some reason I don't understand, this didn't work.
What I ended up doing, which worked, was leave these values at the origin and get just the direction of the ray vector. Then I just moved this vector to the position I needed.